# how to close activity without actually finishing?

Tags: java, android

I want to:

```
open 1, 2, 3 activities
1 > 2 > 3  

back to #2
1 > 2

open #4 activity
1 > 2 > 4

back to #2
1 > 2

restore #3 activity
1 > 2 > 3
```

"Restore" means open previously closed activity without re-creating. 
How can i do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
open 1, 2, 3 activities
1 > 2 > 3  

back to #2
1 > 2          // call startActivity for 2, don't call finish() in 3

open #4 activity
1 > 2 > 4

back to #2
1 > 2

restore #3 activity
1 > 2 > 3      // call startActivity for 3 with intent as Intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_To_FRONT);
```

Comment: but i dont want to re-create activity #2 too

Comment: no problem, dont call finish for activity 2 as well when you navigate from 2 to any other activity, and when you call startActivity for activity 2, set its intent also like above as FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_To_FRONT